# How to enable scrolling while holding alt key in tmux?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, configuration, tmux

I'm wondering what I would put in my .tmux.conf file to allow me to be able to scroll while holding alt? I'm aware of the functionality of `set -g mouse on` however this makes it odd for me to highlight text in my terminal which is a huge problem for me. If anyone has other suggestions also I'd appreciate that. Thanks!

For anyone interested, here is my current configuration:

```
#Quality of life stuff
set -g history-limit 10000
set -g allow-rename off (stops tmux renaming windows automatically)

#Join pane macro (you now use - for vertical split and \ for horizontal)
unbind '"'
unbind %
bind \ split-window -h
bind - split-window -v

# switch panes using Alt-arrow without prefix (Just use alt + arrow keys to change between panes)
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

#Change the default search mode (default is emac) 
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

Comment: Any update on this? I'm also facing this issue, everything i release my left click tmux exits copy mode and goes all the way to the bottom most text.